# VenueController.selectSpace don't highlights Space

Tags: android, here-api

I noticed since `SDK-Version 3.3` that the selected Space isn't highlighted anymore.

My Code for selecting a Space looks like this

```
  private void selectSpaceOnMap(Venue venue, Space space) {

  venueController = mapFragment.getVenueController(venue);
  if (venueController != null && space != null && venue != null) {
       venueController.selectSpace(space);
  }
}
```

The Space is still selected an `OnSpaceSelected()` is called afterwards but the Space is not highlighted. On Tap everything works fine.

Is there a Bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can select a space in a venue with another method (should work in 3.3):

```
private void selectSpaceOnMap(Venue venue, Space space) {

    mapFragment.selectAsync(venue.getId(), space.getId);
}
```

Method selectAsync will also download the venue, if it hasn't done yet.